# several issues - looking for quick wipe of disk and install

Tags: boot, format, usb-installation

I've had Ubuntu version 16, grub and windows installed on my Acer Aspire 5750G.
A recent windows update caused errors. After several issues I just want to wipe the disk and install latest version of ubuntu. I tried this but now there's no boot. The install for Ubuntu version 20 stopped at the grub install with a fatal error (I was installing from USB).

Seeing as I don't care about any of the data, can I just format the disk, after USB booting -then  try ubuntu facility? Then try installing latest version of Ubuntu again?

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 16.  Ubuntu has two product releases, the main server & desktop releases are *yy.mm* in format (such as Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) and since 2016 there are also specialist releases using *yy* format, eg. Ubuntu Core 16. It's Ubuntu Core 16 that is closest to your stated Ubuntu 16, but be aware they are different products to the standard desktop & server releases of Ubuntu (long supported life, but can't use *deb* files being *snap* only). Please clarify your release details.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "-then try ubuntu facility?", otherwise your method sounds workable. You could also backup your home directory and restore it later.

Answer (score 2):

Erasing the old OS is an unnecessary additional action for most users.

If you select the "Erase disk and install Ubuntu," the installer will do all the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can boot from installation media and select the "Try Ubuntu" option.

Then launch the "Disks" application where you can format (erase) your disk(s).

From that point you will have a clean slate to install Ubuntu.  If you are unable to complete this task or proceed with the installation after formatting your hard drive, then there is either something wrong with your hardware, firmware (BIOS), or your installation media is invalid.